# Bricked USB installing LiveCD

Tags: partitioning, usb, live-usb

I used a Verbatim USB to install Ubuntu (into another pen drive).

First I installed the liveCD into the USB, then plugged the usb and started the installation process.
During the installation it either froze or gave me an error (I believe it was something about a corruption in the liveUSB), so I aborted it.

After this problem, from a working ubuntu set up, from the program Disks I formatted and tried to remove the MBR from the USB which I used to try to  install Ubuntu.

It took a long time (20+ mins for a 32G pen drive, with fast format) and at the end it showed an error (which I don't remember. I read it and it was fairly cryptic. All of this happened more than a week ago and I couldn't take the time to investigate it further then).

After the error, the USB has been bricked. It does not show up in Disks and Windows doesn't recognize it as well.

This is the output

```
$ sudo lsusb
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 25a7:2433  
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0951:1666 Kingston Technology DataTraveler G4
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 064e:c21c Suyin Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Notice that buss 02 device 04 is empty. Might it be the device I'm having problems with?
Is there a way to zero out the USB and "unbrick" it?
I really can not see how it was possible to brick a USB while formatting it, I've been installing my OSes in varius configurations for years, and while it might happen to lose data, it never happened to brick a device.

Any helpful input is most appreciated!

*EDIT*

This output is produced when running the command 5 seconds after plugging the USB.

```
$  dmesg | tail -n 25
[47513.393004] wlp3s0: authenticate with bc:f6:85:f2:b1:2f
[47513.417898] wlp3s0: send auth to bc:f6:85:f2:b1:2f (try 1/3)
[47513.419896] wlp3s0: authenticated
[47513.423604] wlp3s0: associate with bc:f6:85:f2:b1:2f (try 1/3)
[47513.428817] wlp3s0: RX AssocResp from bc:f6:85:f2:b1:2f (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=1)
[47513.428935] wlp3s0: associated
[47513.428976] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp3s0: link becomes ready
[77882.517081] psmouse serio1: Touchpad at isa0060/serio1/input0 lost sync at byte 6
[77882.541803] psmouse serio1: Touchpad at isa0060/serio1/input0 - driver resynced.
[78137.396784] psmouse serio1: Touchpad at isa0060/serio1/input0 lost sync at byte 6
[78137.421424] psmouse serio1: Touchpad at isa0060/serio1/input0 - driver resynced.
[78179.021282] psmouse serio1: Touchpad at isa0060/serio1/input0 lost sync at byte 6
[78179.046081] psmouse serio1: Touchpad at isa0060/serio1/input0 - driver resynced.
[81115.174023] usb 2-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 3
[81118.871258] usb 2-1.4: new full-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci
[81118.973960] usb 2-1.4: New USB device found, idVendor=25a7, idProduct=2433
[81118.973969] usb 2-1.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[81118.973974] usb 2-1.4: Product: 2.4G Wireless Device
[81118.973978] usb 2-1.4: Manufacturer: 2.4G
[81118.976399] input: 2.4G 2.4G Wireless Device as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.4/2-1.4:1.0/0003:25A7:2433.0003/input/input16
[81119.031707] hid-generic 0003:25A7:2433.0003: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.01 Keyboard [2.4G 2.4G Wireless Device] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.4/input0
[81119.034970] input: 2.4G 2.4G Wireless Device as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.4/2-1.4:1.1/0003:25A7:2433.0004/input/input17
[81119.087831] hid-generic 0003:25A7:2433.0004: input,hiddev0,hidraw1: USB HID v1.01 Mouse [2.4G 2.4G Wireless Device] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.4/input1
[90119.420279] atkbd serio0: Unknown key released (translated set 2, code 0xe0 on isa0060/serio0).
[90119.420289] atkbd serio0: Use 'setkeycodes e060 <keycode>' to make it known.
```

Comment: You want a terminal or a GUI solution? :)

Comment: Pretty much the exact same thing happened to me with a Maxell flash drive - bricked after attempting to format it, showing "No media" both in Windows and Linux, and unformattable.

Comment: @Videonauth GUI is nice, but I'm not scared from the command line :)

Comment: Unplug the affected drive, plug it back in, and after a few seconds run `dmesg | tail -n 25` and add the output to your question. That will show what's happening in the kernel when the drive is connected.

Comment: Note that according to Google the first device is just a [wireless keyboard/mouse](http://linux-hardware.org/index.php?id=usb:25a7-2433) and is irrelevant to your problem.

Comment: @AndréBorie You are right, I do have a wireless mouse connected to the PC. I also edited the question to add the informations you requested

Comment: You unplugged and plugged back in the mouse instead of the faulty USB drive. Please try again. @Makers_F

Comment: No, I actually unplugged and plugged back the mouse about half an hour earlier than this post. I noticed that as well from the log, so I tried to unplug and plug again the USB over and over again, and the messages still are the same. It really looks like the OS is not detecting the device. Might this be an hardware failure?

Comment: @AndréBorie Forgot to tag you in the previous reply

Comment: @Makers_F yes, looks like a hardware failure. You could open it up and see if the solder joints between the USB connector and the circuit board are intact, and if not you could reflow them with a soldering iron and see if that helps.

Comment: Not sure if this is the cause, but I've had users fry their USB sticks by plugging them in and heavily using them with USB ports on a motherboard where another port was miswired (IIRC it was a spare jumper wrongly placed across the header pins for an unused port). Incidentally the frying only happened when the port was used under Linux and not under Windows.

Answer (score 8):

## GUI Solution:

First and foremost make sure you have `gparted` and `gksudo`installed:

```
sudo apt-get install gparted gksu
```

Then start it with:

```
gksudo gparted
```

Now in the UI switch to your pen-drive via the selector, make sure it is your pen-drive because all what you do from now on will delete all on the selected drive.

[image]

Now click on the shown partition entry(s) and select unmount. After that select 'Create Partition Table ...' from the 'Device' menu and choose as partition type 'msdos'.

[image]
[image]

When that is finished it will show you an 'unallocated' entry for that pen-drive. Right click on it and choose new. In the following dialog choose the file system you want to have it (i.e. FAT, FAT32, ext1-4, this is up to you) and click on 'Add'. Then simply click on the green check-mark to apply your wishes and you're done

[image]

Comment: What if the USB doesn't show up in the selector? Big part of my problem is that there is no /dev/sdX for the pen drive. It only shows /dev/sda (the main HD of this PC) and /dev/sdb (the other USB connected to the PC, a 64G Kingston USB). The 32G Verbatim USB is not shown, and that is the bricked one

Comment: Remove all pen-drives, be sure you unmount the working one before (you not want to brick that one too) and then only plug in the one which is bricked then hit refresh in the file menu i think it is on the gparted window. Maybe even have a reboot in between to make sure your system is at a fresh clean state too. The way i descibed i was able to unbrick a 16 GB and an 8 GB trancend stick

Comment: I can not unmount the other USB since the OS is inside that one! The current PC I'm using is not mine, so I'm not touching the main HDD. It is always unmounted. But I did try to reboot and refresh, and still the verbatim USB does not show up

Comment: Mhmmm weird. Really no clue then, don't you have an own computer with Linux running on it to test?

Comment: Yes I do! I can try on that one tonight!

Comment: Let me know if it works out, I'm usually in the [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room) as well.

Answer (score 3):

If the USB never even shows up as a device, then it's fried.  These USBs can die in one of two ways:

1. The memory card inside it (yes, might just be a micro SD) is EOL, or
2. The electronics in the USB reader dies.

   When you really give up on it, you can pull the USB apart carefully, and if it contains a micro SD, remove the card, put it into a reader and see if it is still usable.  The small button "sticks" are more likely to contain a micro SD, not soldered to anything.

Comment: Huh ? I've never seen a USB stick contain an actual microsd card - In every case I've seen, it's a soldered-on flash chip.

Comment: I guess it's worth the try since it looks like it's dead

Answer (score 0):

if your pc still sees the usb drive but you can't acces it or change partitions you can fully wipe everything by doing [this guide](http://www.howtogeek.com/215349/how-to-remove-an-efi-system-partition-or-gpt-protective-partition-from-a-drive-in-windows/).
Hope I helped

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: The OP can't see it.  lsusb may show something. 
There is always `dd bs=512 if=/dev/zero of=/dev/xxxx` which wipes everything in any case.
Should always unplug everything else in case of short circuits or other excessive loads.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen similar failures caused by excessive dust in the USB port. If it fails in a different port/machine it's likely toast. Check the manufacturers warranty to see if you can get a replacement.